# Populating a structure

Tags: c, memory-management, pointers

I'm solving K&R exercise 1-13:

> Write a program to print a histogram of the lengths of words
>   in its input. It is easy to draw the histogram with the bars horizontal; a 
>   vertical orientation is more challenging.

Although the exercise itself is pretty simple, I've decided to apply a more "professional" approach and encapsulate (is that a correct word?) histogram into a structure:

```
typedef struct {
    /* Legend and character to 'draw' histogram with */
    char **legend, chr;
    /* Histogram data */
    int *data;
    /* Max. data value, bin width, space between bins, max. bin length */
    int datamax, binwidth, binmargin, binlength;
    /* Data and legend array lengths */
    size_t datasize, legendsize;
} chart_t;
```

Because it's still a toy program, I decided to not overcomplicate algorithm so my histogram is limited to only integer data (it's hard to represent floating point values graphically in console anyway).

Overall algorithm works more or less correctly, so I ask to review only my chart creation procedure. The whole point of this was to learn how to use dynamic memory (allocate, free, etc.).

```
#define BINWIDTH_DEFAULT 3
#define BINMARGIN_DEFAULT 1
#define BINLENGTH_DEFAULT 14

/* ... */

chart_t *create_chart(int *data, size_t ds, char **lgnd, size_t ls, char chr) {
    chart_t *out = (chart_t *) malloc(sizeof(chart_t));

    if(out == NULL)
        return NULL;

    out->chr = chr;
    out->datasize = ds;
    out->legendsize = ls;

    out->binwidth = BINWIDTH_DEFAULT;
    out->binmargin = BINMARGIN_DEFAULT;
    out->binlength = BINLENGTH_DEFAULT;

    out->data = (int *) calloc(ds, sizeof(int));

    if(out->data == NULL) {
        free(out);
        return NULL;
    }

    memcpy(out->data, data, ds);

    int dmax = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < ds; i++)
        if(data[i] > dmax)
            dmax = data[i];

    out->datamax = dmax;

    char **legend = (char **) calloc(ls, sizeof(char *));

    for(int i = 0; i < ls; i++) {
        size_t len = strlen(lgnd[i]);

        if(len == 0)
            continue;

        char *curstr = (char *) calloc(len+1, sizeof(char));

        if(curstr == NULL) {
            if(i > 1)
                for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                    free(legend[j]);

            free(legend);
            free(out);

            return NULL;
        }

        strncpy(curstr, lgnd[i], len+1);

        legend[i] = curstr;
    }

    return out;
}
```

Haven't I missed anything? Do I have any potential memory problems in my procedure?

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- A case `cursor == NULL` does not `free(out->data)`.
- A test `i > 1` is *strange*, and buggy. If `i` happens to be 1, you are leaking memory `legend[0]` points to.
- [Do not cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/3403834)
- Calling `calloc` in `char *curstr = (char *) calloc(len+1, sizeof(char));` is an overkill:

  - `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1, and
  - the contents of `curstr` is immediately overwritten by `strncpy`, so its zero initialization was a waste of time.
- The body of the loop spells out

  ```
      legend[i] = strdup(lgnd[i]);
  ```

  in a very obfuscated way.
- Given no context, it is very hard to see why do you need all that dynamic allocation at all.

Answer (score 6):

One additional problem is that the `memcpy` is not copying all the data.  It is copying `ds` *bytes*, not `ds` *elements*.  So it should be

```
    memcpy(out->data, data, ds * sizeof(*data));
```

which also makes the zero initializing done by `calloc` for `out->data` a waste of time.

Comment: Good catch. Missed that.

Comment: Oh, that's a dumb mistake. Should've noticed it myself. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to all the other great advice you got, there's one that stood out for me but wasn't mentioned.

You allow creating your structure *only* by dynamic memory allocation. So if you later wanted to embed that structure into another, you'd be forced to use a pointer. That's not a problem in and of itself, but I think that unless you *must* have a particular allocation scheme, it's not bad to separate the initialization from the allocation itself. So you'd have something like

```
void initialize_chart(chart_t *out, int *data, size_t ds, char **lgnd, size_t ls, char chr) {
  /* As you did before */
}

chart_t *create_chart(int *data, size_t ds, char **lgnd, size_t ls, char chr) {
    chart_t *out = malloc(sizeof(chart_t));
    /* Your verification here */
    initialize_chart(out, data, size_t, lgnd, ls, chr);
    return out;
}
```

Now you can easily embed `chart_t` into other structures by value (or create `chart_t` variables of automatic storage duration), if the need ever arises. The initialization is the same.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** I've rewritten my code according to vnp's answer and separated initialization and creation as StoryTeller suggested (also I wonder whether it's possible to reference people in posts).

```
chart_t *initialize_chart(chart_t *chart, int *data, size_t ds, char **lgnd, size_t ls, char chr) {
    if(chart == NULL)
        return NULL;

    chart->chr = chr;
    chart->datasize = ds;
    chart->legendsize = ls;

    chart->binwidth = BINWIDTH_DEFAULT;
    chart->binmargin = BINMARGIN_DEFAULT;
    chart->binlength = BINLENGTH_DEFAULT;

    chart->data = malloc(sizeof(*data) * ds);

    if(chart->data == NULL) {
        free(chart);
        return NULL;
    }

    memcpy(chart->data, data, sizeof(*data) * ds);

    int dmax = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < ds; i++)
        if(data[i] > dmax)
            dmax = data[i];

    chart->datamax = dmax;

    char **legend = calloc(ls, sizeof(char *));

    for(int i = 0; i < ls; i++) {
        size_t len = strlen(lgnd[i]);

        if(len == 0) {
            /* This situtation should be handled more sensibly, like, 
             * probably, converting i to string and using it as a legend
             * entry, but (as far as I know for now) there's no 
             * straightforward way to do it in C so I'll write it later.
             */
            continue;
        }

        legend[i] = strdup(lgnd[i]);

        if(legend[i] == NULL) {
            for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                free(legend[j]);

            free(legend);
            free(chart->data);
            free(chart);

            return NULL;
        }
    }

    return chart;
}

chart_t *create_chart(int *data, size_t ds, char **lgnd, size_t ls, char chr) {
    chart_t *chart = malloc(sizeof(chart_t));

    if(chart == NULL)
        return NULL;

    chart = initialize_chart(chart, data, ds, lgnd, ls, chr);

    return chart;
}
```

`initialize_chart` function returns `chart_t` because there can be errors during initialization and returning pointer (or `NULL`) may simplify checking  whether function call went successfully in ifs and loops. It also operates on it's `chart` argument and does not create a temporary variable. I wonder if it's a good thing to do.

Concerning dynamic allocation I thought that it would be a good thing to deep copy the data into the chart in case programmer (if it was a library) modifies or corrupts their own copy. On the other hand, the charts are kinda supposed to be dynamic, so let's think it was a dumb architectural decision.

I also wonder if `char **legend = calloc(ls, sizeof(char *));` is an overkill since allocated memory is rewritten (and even if we just keep skipping empty lines, we have `legendsize` to constraint our loops from printing nonsense from non-initialized memory).

I probably shouldn't be so concerned about this task, but I'm still learning and for me it's more of a "code design" lesson than programming one. Thank you everyone.

Comment: If you return a pointer to support error checking, then you should really be doing error checking effectively. A blind `chart = initialize_chart(...)` is going to leak in case of an error.

Comment: But in this case if `initialize_chart` returns `NULL`, `create_chart` also will return `NULL` and it's now a responsibility of `create_chart` caller to check whether result is `NULL`. Or you're talking about indicating errors properly like setting `errno`?

Comment: I'm talking about you `malloc`ing  something without `free`ing it

Comment: But in case of initialization error, there's `free(chart)` in `initialize_chart` function. But I guess it isn't a good thing either. Thanks.

Comment: And what if `chart` wasn't allcoated with `malloc`? I posted my answer to suggest you support *other* allocation schemes. If it was a pointer to an automatic variable, you'd be in trouble just freeing it. If a function didn't allocate something itself, it has not business freeing it blindly either in case of error.

Comment: That's what I thought as 'why it's not a good thing'. I'll fix it as soon as I get to computer.